# Opening PDF from multi-part XML soap response with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, angular, pdf

I am trying to open a pdf from a multipart XML soap response.

The FrameWork I am using is Angular 6

### Here is my soap request

```
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open('POST', 'url', true);
 strRequest =
 '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
 '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="urn://ecm.rmv.com/document/2013/06/01">' +
     '<soapenv:Header/>' +
     '<soapenv:Body>' +
         '<ns:searchDocumentRequest>' +
             '<ns:repositoryId>CrashReport</ns:repositoryId>' +
             '<ns:actorId>CrashPortal</ns:actorId>' +
             '<ns:documentType>CrashReport</ns:documentType>' +
             '<ns:properties>' +
             '<ns:property name="CrashDocNum"/>' +
             '</ns:properties>' +
             '<ns:filters>' +
                 '<ns:filter>' +
                     '<ns:condition property="CrashDocNum" operator="eq" value="PR201104900247"/>' +
                 '</ns:filter>' +
             '</ns:filters>' +
             '<ns:options>' +
                 '<ns:option name="retrieveContent">true</ns:option>' +
             '</ns:options>' +
         '</ns:searchDocumentRequest>' +
     '</soapenv:Body>' +
 '</soapenv:Envelope>'
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'searchDocument');
xmlhttp.send(strRequest);
```

### Below is a partial of the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS, HEAD, PUT, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type, soapaction
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="uuid:2112c517-ca6a-433f-b264-fd363b09aead"; start="<root.message@cxf.apache.org>"; start-info="text/xml"
Content-Language: en-US
Date: Fri, 04 Jan 2019 00:27:18 GMT
Content-Length: 514549


--uuid:2112c517-ca6a-433f-b264-fd363b09aead
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <searchDocumentResponse xmlns="urn://ecm.rmv.com/document/2013/06/01">
            <success>true</success>
            <documents>
            ...
            </documents>
        </searchDocumentResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

--uuid:2112c517-ca6a-433f-b264-fd363b09aead
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <adea784f-5e63-4b03-9736-bcdbf456bebe-1@urn://ecm.rmv.com/document/2013/06/01>

%PDF-1.6
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</DGAP_FIndex 1/DGAP_FList[/APF1/Helvetica 5 0 R]/DGAP_GSIndex 1/DGAP_GSList[/APGS1 6 0 R]/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 7 0 R/Pages 3 0 R/StructTreeRoot 8 0 R/Type/Catalog>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Length 3591/Subtype/XML/Type/Metadata>>stream
<?xpacket begin="ï»¿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
    <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 4.2.1-c043 52.389687, 2009/06/02-13:20:35        ">
       <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
          <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/">
             <xmp:ModifyDate>2017-09-06T14:32:15-05:00</xmp:ModifyDate>
             <xmp:CreateDate>2017-09-06T14:32:15-05:00</xmp:CreateDate>
             <xmp:MetadataDate>2017-09-06T14:32:14-05:00</xmp:MetadataDate>
             <xmp:CreatorTool>Appligent Redax Enterprise Server 3.1.2</xmp:CreatorTool>
          </rdf:Description>
              ...
          <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:pdfx="http://ns.adobe.com/pdfx/1.3/">
             <pdfx:Appligent>Redax Enterprise Server 3.1.2 Linux Kernel 2.6 64bit Dec  6 2010 Library 9.0.1</pdfx:Appligent>
          </rdf:Description>
       </rdf:RDF>
    </x:xmpmeta>                                                                                                                  
<?xpacket end="w"?>

endstream
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Count 3/Kids[9 0 R 10 0 R 11 0 R]/MediaBox[0.0 0.0 614.4 792.0]/Resources<</Font<</APF1 5 0 R>>>>/Type/Pages>>
endobj
8 0 obj
<</K 12 0 R/ParentTree 13 0 R/ParentTreeNextKey 3/Type/StructTreeRoot>>
endobj
12 0 obj
<</K[14 0 R 15 0 R 16 0 R 17 0 R 18 0 R 19 0 R 20 0 R 21 0 R 22 0 R 23 0 R 24 0 R 25 0 R 26 0 R 27 0 R 28 0 R 29 0 R 30 0 R 31 0 R 32 0 R 33 0 R 34 0 R 35 0 R 36 0 R 37 0 R 38 0 R 39 0 R]/P 8 0 R/S/Document>>
endobj
13 0 obj
...
0000429477 00000 n
0000429405 00000 n
0000429333 00000 n
trailer
<</Size 3721/Root 1 0 R/Info 4 0 R/ID[<782E5FB7ACA6B2110A0020744EB2FD7F><AAC95FB7ACA6B2110A00D84D84010000>]>>
startxref
438658
%%EOF

--uuid:2112c517-ca6a-433f-b264-fd363b09aead--
```

I have tried multiple things but nothing seems to work:

**Note:** if I save the response in a text file then change the extension to pdf the pdf will show up.

A lot of what I have read online show code about converting it to Base64 but I don't know if I can do that given what the soap response is giving back.

What I have tried to do in my last attempt at this is use the boundary to split up the xml to get the part that starts with **%PDF-1.6**. After I split it up I run the code below to download the file.

```
downloadReponse(doc_data) {
    var newBlob = new Blob([doc_data], {type: "application/pdf"})
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = "file.pdf";

    link.click();
    setTimeout(function () {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, 10000);
}
```

This does download the file but when I open it the pdf opens with three blanks page. Orginally I wanted to make it open in a new tab but the code I found online only works with Base64.

Comment: try this `var btoa_doc_data = btoa(doc_data);` then create the blob with `btoa_doc_data`

Comment: Pavlo I just tried that but I get an error, 
Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.

Comment: Isn't this the end of the PDF "7 0 obj"

Comment: So I thank you for telling me about the **%%EOF** I had some lingering characters there for how I was splitting the file. When I do  `encodeURIComponent(btoa(doc_data))` it gave me the same error but `btoa(encodeURIComponent(doc_data))` gave something back but now when I open the pdf it say 
Failed to load PDF document.